# Carrierwave - destroy object only after mounted files have been deleted from storage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-s3, carrierwave

Carrierwave deletes files after the destruction of the object has been completed:

```
after_commit :remove_avatar! :on => :destroy
```

https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave

I have a worker that deletes the files. If one of the workers timeout when deleting a file from S3 I lose track of the files on S3 and my bucket becomes a mess (since my object that had the mounted file is gone from my DB).

How should I handle this?
Directly call `remove_avatar!` before my `object.destroy` and then `skip_callback?` Is it safe?

Answer (score 8):

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  mount_uploader :avatar, AvatarUploader

  before_destroy :clean_s3

private
  def clean_s3
    avatar.remove!
    avatar.thumb.remove! # if you have thumb version or any other version
  rescue Excon::Errors::Error => error
    puts "Something gone wrong"
    false
  end
end
```

Comment: In addition, check this if you want to clean up the leftover empty directories https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/wiki/How-to%3A-Make-a-fast-lookup-able-storage-directory-structure