# Rails, carrierwave removing file from s3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, carrierwave

I can successfully create and destroy my model which saves files to s3 with `fog` with its associated file on s3.

But when I am disconnected from the internet I can only delete my model from database.
`object.destroy!` removes object from database and shows `#<Excon::Errors::SocketError: getaddrinfo: nodename nor servname provided, or not known (SocketError)>` On s3 file still exists. How can I prevent deleting objects from database if something went wrong with deleting file from s3?

Comment: Duplicates http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22391183/carrierwave-destroy-object-only-after-mounted-files-have-been-deleted-from-sto?rq=1

Comment: Answered http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22391183/carrierwave-destroy-object-only-after-mounted-files-have-been-deleted-from-sto/24182513#24182513